# Please how can i convert arrays of charcters back to a string to display the words.(caesar cypher) In C language

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I am two weeks old in learning the C language, and I have been trying to solve this problem for about 5 days now.

I have a program that is supposed to take this input: hello, world and print out the kind of encrypted word uryyb, jbeyq. My program is working good printing the words but printing them character by character on top of each other.

I want to know please if there a way I can convert those single characters back to a string so that when I run the program, it will print out the words as strings instead of character by character.

```
 if (isupper(user_input[i]))
        {
            //calculating the values for the capital letters!
            alphabet_index = user_input[i] - 'A'; // 65 is the ascii number of big A!
            
            calculate_value = (alphabet_index + key) % 26;
            
            encipher = calculate_value + 'A';
            printf("cyphertext: %c\n", encipher);
```

that is part of my code,, When I print that cyphertext using the encipher variable, it prints out the characters on top of each other but I want to print them like normal words. I have tried all I can to no avail.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Thanks to everyone that contributed to my question, your answers made me realize my mistake which I have fixed, I just needed to print everything I needed in different places. problem solved. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Simply stop printing extra things? (`printf("cyphertext: %c\n", encipher);` -> `printf("%c", encipher);` or `putchar(encipher);`)

Comment: It's not clear what "on top of each other means", but the "\n" in your `printf` is a new line, so that might a clue.

Comment: There isn't enough code here for us to see how to best fix the problem. This code looks fine, and could form the basis of a function to encipher a character. The structure around this code is what needs fixing.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to print it with the cyphertext in other to pass the automated test, for example when the user inputs 13 as a key and then input hello, world as a plain text, my program is supposed to print ciphertext: uryyb, jbeyq, my program prints the answer correctly but places it on each other character by character like this:
ciphertext: u
ciphertext: r
ciphertext: y
ciphertext: y
ciphertext: ,
and so on and all the effort I have made so far to print it like this: ciphertext: uryyb, jbeyq have failed, bf the post i tried removing newline, also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '\n' from print statement.

Comment: They also need to remove "cyphertext: ".

Comment: Yeah didn't pay any attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("cyphertext: %c\n", encipher);` will print each character on a separate line. To have them form a single string on display, remove the unnecessary parts from the print and change it to:

`printf("%c", encipher);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is small example of how you can do it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  char inp_str[]= "HelloWorld";
  int str_len = strlen(inp_str) + 1; // get lenght of input string
  char *out_str = (char *)malloc(str_len); // allocate memmory for output buffer
  memset(out_str, str_len, 0); // clear output buffer with zeros

  for (int i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
  {
    char cur_val = inp_str[i] + 6; // Caesar cipher with shift of 6
    if (cur_val > 'z')
      cur_val -= 32;
    out_str[i] = cur_val; // encrypt and store result in out_string
  }

  printf("Before: %s\nAfter: %s\n", inp_str, out_str);

  free(out_str); // dont forget to free memmory that you allocated
  return 0;
}
```